# System of nonlinear complex-valued equations using Solve

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

I'm trying to figure out the proper syntax to use in Mathematica to solve the following system of $6$ nonlinear complex-valued equations in $6$ unknowns $a,b,c,d,e,f$, where $a,d,f \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b,c,e \in \mathbb{C}$: $$\begin{cases} a^2-|b|^2-|c|^2=1, \\ |b|^2-d^2-|e|^2=-1, \\ |c|^2-|e|^2-f^2=-1, \\ ab-bd-c\bar{e}=0, \\ \bar{b}c-de-ef=0, \\ \bar{c}a-\bar{e}\bar{b}-f\bar{c}=0,  \end{cases}$$ where $a^2 \geq 1$. I wanted the solution to have a mix of complex and real values. After some brute force I actually found a particular solution: $$a=d= \pm{\sqrt{2}}, b= \pm{i}, c=e= 0,f=\pm{1}.$$ I was wondering if Mathematica using Solve could find other solutions. Here is the code that I used:

```
 Solve[a^2 - Abs[b]^2 - Abs[c]^2 == 
   1 && Abs[b]^2 - d^2 - Abs[e]^2 ==-1 && Abs[c]^2 - Abs[e]^2 - f^2 == -1 && 
 a b - b d - c e\[Conjugate] == 0 && b\[Conjugate] c - d e - e f == 0 && 
  c\[Conjugate] a - e\[Conjugate] b\[Conjugate] - f c\[Conjugate] == 
   0, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, ?]
```

My apologies, I still don't have the hang on how to enter Mathematica code here, even after keeping four spaces. My issue is what to put in "?" for the system to be solved.

Comment: There are some syntax errors in here. Such as when multiplying variables, you have to put a space between them. Also, you can't have brackets around `Abs[]`, you can just put `Abs[]^2` and that should work.

Comment: Square brackets are used for functions such as `Abs[]`, round brackets are use for grouping such as `(a+b)*c`

Comment: @J_Nat: I tried doing that, and then setting the domain to Complexes but to no avail.

Comment: You have to have spaces between variables to multiply them.

Comment: @Feyre: Please see the latest edit by J_Nat that I just approved, where spaces have been kept between the variables being multiplied and the brackets have been removed from outside of the absolute values.

Comment: What should I do about the domain, because when I use Complexes, the implemented code keeps on running, and I have to abort the evaluation!

Comment: Complex domain is standard, try confining specifically the reals.

Comment: As a strategy for approaching a new computer language, it is often a good idea to start simple and work your way towards complexity. For your case, how about choosing a 2 complex-variable problem with some of the smae features, and working your way up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tackle this as follows

```
eqn = a^2 - Abs[b]^2 - Abs[c]^2 == 1 && 
  Abs[b]^2 - d^2 - Abs[e]^2 == -1 && Abs[c]^2 - Abs[e]^2 - f^2 == -1 &&
   a b - b d - c e\[Conjugate] == 0 && 
  b\[Conjugate] c - d e - e f == 0 && 
  c\[Conjugate] a - e\[Conjugate] b\[Conjugate] - f c\[Conjugate] == 0
(* a^2 - Abs[b]^2 - Abs[c]^2 == 
  1 && -d^2 + Abs[b]^2 - Abs[e]^2 == -1 && -f^2 + Abs[c]^2 - 
   Abs[e]^2 == -1 && 
 a b - b d - c Conjugate[e] == 0 && -d e - e f + c Conjugate[b] == 0 &&
  a Conjugate[c] - f Conjugate[c] - Conjugate[b] Conjugate[e] == 0 *)
```

Define separate variables for the real and imaginary parts of those that are complex

```
subst = Thread[
  Flatten[{Re /@ {b, c, e}, Im /@ {b, c, e}}] -> {rb, rc, re, ib, ic, 
    ie}]
(* {Re[b] -> rb, Re[c] -> rc, Re[e] -> re, Im[b] -> ib, Im[c] -> ic, 
 Im[e] -> ie} *)
```

Rewrite the equations as real expressions using these

```
eqn2 = ComplexExpand[(Re /@ eqn) && (Im /@ eqn), {b, c, e}, 
   TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] /. subst
(* a^2 - ib^2 - ic^2 - rb^2 - rc^2 == 
  1 && -d^2 + ib^2 - ie^2 + rb^2 - re^2 == -1 && -f^2 + ic^2 - ie^2 + 
   rc^2 - re^2 == -1 && -ic ie + a rb - d rb - rc re == 0 && 
 ib ic + rb rc - d re - f re == 0 && 
 ib ie + a rc - f rc - rb re == 0 && 
 a ib - d ib + ie rc - ic re == 0 && -d ie - f ie + ic rb - ib rc == 
  0 && -a ic + f ic + ie rb + ib re == 0 *)

vars = Flatten[{a, d, f, Re /@ {b, c, e}, Im /@ {b, c, e}}] /. subst
(* {a, d, f, rb, rc, re, ib, ic, ie} *)
```

I now find that `Solve` and `Reduce` struggle to solve these equations.  The relevant expressions would be

```
(*Solve[eqn2,vars,Reals]*)
(*Solve[eqn2,vars,Reals]*)
```

Looking for a numerical solution seems to give a dense set of solutions, suggesting that we  don't really have 9 independent equations.  To solve the equations 100 times from random starting points, evaluate

```
Table[FindRoot[eqn2, 
   Transpose[{vars, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Length[vars]]}], 
   MaxIterations -> 1000], {100}] // Chop
```

*EDIT*

There is a trap for the unwary here.  If we don't specify the solution domain, `Complex` is assumed by default and we get incorrect answers.  For example

```
NSolve[eqn2, vars]
```

returns 512 solutions, but most of them are complex.

```
NSolve[eqn2, vars, Reals]
```

finds only two solutions, for some reason.  In comparison, `FindRoot` finds large numbers of apparently valid solutions.

Comment: This looks quite complicated. Is there anything simpler?

Comment: I think the only complicated part of it is the equations themselves.

Comment: @MichaelE2 are you sure?  `NSolve[eqn2,vars]` does return 512 solutions.  However, almost all of these include complex values.  `NSolve[eqn2,vars,Reals]` gives only two solutions  However, `FindRoot` seems to give other genuine solutions.

Comment: D'oh!  Careless of me -- sorry.